# How to create multiple overlapping underlines under different subsections of text

Tags: html, css, underline

I want to create a feature where users can annotate different subsections of a text. When an annotation has been made an underline will show under that part of the text. How could I create this effect with HTML/CSS?

[image: Underlining effect]

Comment: Look here for another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861062/text-with-multiple-underlines

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this kind of underlining effect with linear gradients :

```css
span {
    line-height: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, green 1px, white 1px, transparent 1px);
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
.two {
    line-height: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.three {
    line-height: 28px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="one">Lorem ipsum <span class="two">dolor</span> sit amet,</span>consectetur adipiscing elit. <span class="one">Maecenas <span class="two"><span class="three">finibus</span></span></span><span class="two"> aliquam eros eget accumsan.Pellentesque quis <span class="three">diam lacus.</span></span></p>
```

*Note that I didn't insert the vendor prefixes for the linear gradient*

Comment: simple and efective !

Comment: @web-tiki Thanks. How can I do something like the top two lines that overlap "Tempor" in my example?

Comment: @PeterR I edited the answer with an overlapping line example.

Comment: Looks good on Firefox.  On Chrome there is a sliiight gap between the `.two` underlines of "finibus" and "aliquam".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that directly with HTML and CSS.

You can do that in a modern browser writing custom code and [creating a custom Canvas/SVG solution](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp). But that's a very hard to do work. Try looking for some graphics library that can help you do it.