# Add multiple nested underline styles for a same text

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Currently, I am working on a project that includes a specific feature to add multiple underline styles to a single text. In this scenario, the text may contain two types of insertions by the user, which may also include misspellings.
I need to style the text with wavy red for misspelling, orange underline for suggestion available and green underline for indicate that is inserted by the user.
I need something like below (please ignore my poor drawing)
[image]

I currently have below custom react component:

```
export type TextType = "inserted" | "misspelled" | "unknown_word" | "Grammer_suggestion"

export interface CustomTextProps extends TypographyProps {
  label: string;
  type?: TextType
}

export const CustomText = ({ label, ...props }: CustomTextProps) => {

  const textStyles: SxProps = {
    textUnderlineOffset: "4px",
    textDecorationLine: "underline",
    textDecorationColor: "red"
    textDecorationThickness: "3px",
    textDecorationStyle: "wavy", 
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant="body2" sx={textStyles} {...props}>
        {label}
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861062/text-with-multiple-underlines

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VwRBjzZ?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

As i know you cant directly make with different underline styles.But you can make something like this with html, css and linear-gradient [image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Kvu.png)

```css
span {
  line-height: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, green 1px, white 1px, transparent 1px);
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
.two {
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.three {
  line-height: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <span class="one"
        >Lorem ipsum
        <span class="two">dolor <span class="three">diam lacus.</span></span>
        sit amet,</span
      >
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```